# Maximal inequality for Bessel process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $W = \{W_t, t \geq 0\}$ be an $m$-dimensional Brownian motion.
The process $( \|W_t\|, \mathcal{F}_t )_{t ≥ 0}$ is then a Bessel process, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm in $R^m$.

**Question.** Using Statement 1 (with the function $h(x) = e^tx$ and $t>0$), prove that the inequality is true for every $s>0$ and all $x>\sqrt{ms}$:

$$P(\sup\limits_{t∈[0,s]} ||W_t||≥x) ≤ (\frac{sd}{ex^2})^{-m/2} e^{-x^2/(2s)}$$

**Statement 1:**
Let $h: R \rightarrow R_+ $ be a non-decreasing convex function and $(X_n, \mathcal{F}_n)_{1 \leqslant n \leqslant N}$ be a submartingale. Then for any $ u \in R$ and $t>0$

\begin{equation}
P( \max\limits_{1 \leqslant n \leqslant N} X_n \geqslant u ) \leqslant \mathbb{E} h(t X_n)/h(tu).
\end{equation}

**Solution:**

1. First, I need to prove that the process is a submartingale, that is, to prove the most important condition that:

$$E(\|W_t\| \, | \, \mathcal{F}_s)\geq \| W_s \|$$

And since $\mathcal{F}_s$ is a natural filtration, I need to show that

$$E(\|W_t\| \, | \, W_s)\geq \| W_s \|$$

We know that $\|W_t\|= \sqrt{W_1^2 +...+W_t^2}$

And this is where I got stuck.

2. Then I was only able to substitute $h$ and get this expression:

$P(\max\limits_{0 \leqslant t \leqslant m} \|W_t\| \geq u)\leq \frac{E(e^{t^2\|W_t\|})}{e^{t^2 u}}$

I'm having trouble calculating the expectation of such complex functions, so I'm hoping for some advice.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please edit your question with your attempts, instead of showing your attempts in the comments. This is to guarantee your question meets the site's standards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice!

Comment: I've made some edits to your typesetting. Please see this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future reference.